# Trigger Dataflows refresh in Power BI Service right after SQL Server refreshes dataset

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery, google-cloud-dataflow, power-automate

We are using SQL Server as virtual machine, that we are connecting to Power BI Service (Pro) with Data Flows. Now, we are looking for some solutions using Power Automate (or else) to automate refreshes from SQL > PBI (DFs) and Datasets.

So, is there any possibility to get triggered on Power BI Service by SQL Server when its done with data refresh, and then to start refreshing dataflows + datasets, so that we are having minimum or "0" time between refreshes of SQL vs Power BI Service.

What is now the case, we got automated processes governed by Microsoft to update our SQLs during the night, and then from 06:00 power automate is running dataflows automatically.., but as you can imagine, there can be timing problem, or any other issue that can refresh lets say "empty" or data with errors, without knowing it at first place.

I am not very familiar with Power Automate (some basics yes), but is this possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What triggers your SQL Server's update?  Generally either use a single scheduling and automation solution, or have the SQL Server update "trigger" the power automate flow as its last step.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/http-connectors/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It is triggered by Task Scheduler and Powershell script..okay, I will check that